# How to create 3d metallic man in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, gradient, shadows, blur, lighting-effects

Update:1
After working with blender . I got the concept how to create. Just for motivating i am sharing a sample. Here i drawn simple sample outline . Lighting and more 3d parts not worked out in this image.however i want to convey that i got understanding of some important basic concept.
[image]

[image: adobe illustrator 3d man]

I tried almost all filters in inkscape. in that materials -> metallized paint also not giving the result like in illustrator. Any blur,gradient,shading and lighting guide will be more helpful for me.
my present design in inkscape given below.
[image]

Comment: Welcome! In broad general terms, you aren't going to find any canned "filters" or "effects" which will mimic the 3D lighting like that used in the top image. In most non-3d vector software you need to *manually* create highlights and shadows.

Comment: Thanks @Scott i will try to find out.

Comment: So the thing your trying to do us a bit challenging in a vector application. A vector application is like using scissors cut paper then layer those on top of eachother. Now if you tried to do the the sample images you have by cutting paper pieces you would instantly understand that its a bit challenging to get the result you want. But if your really good with your scissors sure why not. But not terribly productive and ultimately not something your vector app should be good at. (Now illustrator is moving towards more real 3D so thats another case, still i dont see me ever really using that)

Comment: (But illustrators 3D most often isnt vectors, why Id want to use illustrator to make bitmap images is beyond my understanding. There are better 3D applications, there are better painting applications, but there is hardly no better vector application out there that would be as PDF compilant wysiwyg app as illustrator. There are better 3D applications for vector outlines though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you could recreate something like this in Inkscape manually, I think it would be better to use 3D modelling software such as Blender. I strongly suspect that is how the original was made.

If you do want to do it in Inkscape, I wouldn't rely on SVG filters. They aren't very controllable or good enough quality IMHO, and there are problems with rendering SVG filters in different browsers anyway. It's a sure route to disaster if your intended output is SVG for the web.

You could build an illustration like this simply by using gradients and blurs for highlights/shadows, variable power strokes, etc. But this is a completely manual process.

Here's a quick incomplete example showing what is possible

[image]

Here's [the link to the Inkscape SVG](https://svgshare.com/i/pQM.svg) if you want to examine how it was constructed. I don't encourage you to use this, and include here it only for educational purposes.  To copy an image like this would likely be copyright infringement.

Comment: I will check this. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, this image can be done by everyone with illustrator within 7 to 10 minutes . So no need to worry about copyright infringement.I am just want to understand how to create like this just by using basic image options and opensource software like inkscape.

Comment: @kaviyarasu The length of time taken to copy something has no bearing on whether it is copyright infringement.  Copyright is automatically conferred to the creator of a graphic.  If you don't have permission to copy this graphic then it **IS** most likely copyright infringement.

Comment: oh friends come on , you didn't get the point . To be super clear  , Actually a youtube creator shown a full video tutorial of how to do this image yourself with illustrator .i can create with free trial or some of my friends adobe account & i am not just talking about this image.the concept. Many of us already have an idea like this and next we saw lot of images like this online . We have to convey the question perfectly .for that here i took that image for sample.My wish is i want to inflate,metallic,3d ,shadows view in opensource softwares if not available how to do with gradients and blur.